# TFS / MTM 2015 - invite users to re-run tests after bugfix

Tags: tfs, regression-testing, mtm

Scope: **I need a possibility to re-assign, on a bugs basis, the test case again to the same tester/testers which has reported this bug.**

MTM 2015 got this "Verify function" under the testing center menu "Test" - Verify bugs and by right clicking on a bug in the list.

Now when I do this, it'll start the MTM test runner with me as the assigned tester. But thats actually not what I need.

I came as far as this with my researches:

TFS 2015 hasn't any "Verify" function - only available from version 2017.1 or later ([more here on section: Verify a bug, re-run tests ...](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/manage-bugs))

So could anybody help me out of this (updating to TFS 2017 or later is no option for the moment)?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and effective way still is using bug workitem  workflow to track the process. Even without the verify function in TFS2015, you still could link your test case in the bug workitem. You need to customize the bug work item type. Add a custom filed such as retest and add a condition (retest filed need to change to pass) during the transform from active to resolve.

Then just set "assign to" filed = work item creator to make sure  the test case run again by the same tester/testers which has reported this bug.

However this will create a new test result in a new test run. It will not update the original test result. If you just want to rerun failed test cases from TFS 2015. Unfortunately ,this is not an inbuilt feature. More details please refer this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2155) in GitHub.

Comment: Hi Patrick,

thanks for your reply, but I got a few additional questions on it.

I only got Under "New work item" the options to create:
Bug, Epic, Feature, Issue, Task, Test Case and User story.

Which one is the best to use?
Once I created the work item, I will be the crator of it and not the initial tester, or did I get it wrong?

Getting a new test result will be ok for me.

Comment: @MarcS. I mean you could track Your Bugs Using Microsoft Test Manager  . When the test failed the tester could create a bug work item and assign to the developer to fix the bug(guess you), when you fixed the bug reassign the bug work item to the creator(the test). He could rerun the test again. This is the workflow. Details follow [Analyze failed tests and track bugs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286731(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @Parick, ok I see, thanks.

We only use TFS Web for the testers, I'm the only one using additionally MTM.(also a question of licence fees)

I think TFS 2017.1 might resolve the problem...

Comment: @MarcS. In web, you could also do this, when the testers run the test case, there will be a dialogue pop-up with some test steps, in the top, there will be a create bug button, with this you could create a bug work item which related to the test case.

Comment: yes, thats's the way we used to do, but 2 points on this:

<br />
- how will the tester, after a bunch of test cases done and after a couple of  weeks been passed, be able to find his own created bugs (resp. 
even more bugs per test case)?

- how not make landing to tester on a test case in the "edit" mode, but in the "run test" - mode?